# Is there a Facebook privacy selection widget (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, facebook, widget, privacy

The "post to wall" on the facebook site offers a quite sophisticated widget to select whom the posted contents should be shared with. (Dropdown with Public, Friends, Custom...)

Is this widget also available through the JavaScript SDK somehow (I could not find) or does anyone know a JavaScript widget from an external source like that? What I am looking for is only a privacy widget, not the whole post to wall.

To provide reasonable privacy settings for user interactions a widget of that comfort is eventually needed or should at least be available to include with little effort in every facebook application. I think it would be a good approach towards better user privacy if such a widget would be made available in the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this exists. Your best bet is having your own list of the accepted privacy values (EVERYONE, ALL_FRIENDS, NETWORKS_FRIENDS, FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS, CUSTOM - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) and validating it if required.

Comment: That's what I fear because designing and developing the "custom..." privacy selection dialog would be more effort than the whole remainder of the app I am going to develop.

Comment: you could use the friend selector to compile a list of UID for people to include/exclude?https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/friend-selector/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector/

Comment: Could not find anything suitable at the moment, so I'll go to implement the option to make things visible only to all friends or everyone in the first version. Maybe I'll have enough time later to implement a sophisticated privacy selection.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too difficult to build your own widget to select friends for a custom recipient list. 
As an illustration, my version of what you want to achieve uses an autocomplete field to select friends which stores the IDs. Theses are passed to the post function as a comma separated string of IDs which are placed directly into the PHP CURL function below, which I hope will explain how to achieve your goal on the server end of things:

```
    $message = stripslashes(urldecode($_POST['msg']));
    $recips = $_POST['recip']; // your comma delimited IDs
    $data = array(
            'access_token' => $token,
            'privacy' => '{"value": "CUSTOM", "friends": "SOME_FRIENDS", "allow": "' . $recips  . '"}',
            'message' => $message
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

I have only included the relevant sections for customising the privacy.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the addition :) I am aware that is not too difficult to write but it takes a long time and effort until it has the same functionality as the facebook one and looks as good, automatically fetches friends lists etc using the FB JavaScript SDK,... And after all it is reinventing the wheel all over agian.